# Issue with Option Filling -> Axis

Tags: plotting, filling

In mathematica 12.0, the following code

```
Show[
 {Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[i, 1], x] Exp[-Sqrt[i]/4] /. 
      i -> Range[1, 3, 2] // Evaluate, {x, -3, 8}, PlotRange -> All, 
     Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> {Black, Gray}],
   Table[Plot[
     PDF[NormalDistribution[i, 1], x] Exp[-Sqrt[i]/4] /. 
       i -> Range[1, 3, 2] // Evaluate, {x, k, k + 1}, 
     PlotRange -> Full, Filling -> Axis, Axes -> None,
     PlotStyle -> {ColorData[10][4 + k], 
       Darker[ColorData[10][4 + k], 0.3]}], {k, -3, 5}]} // Flatten,
 PlotRange -> {0, 1/3}]
```

produces the following plot

[image]

It seems to me the (square like white) gap near the bottom is unexpected (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue caused by differing vertical positions of `Axis` across plots with filling.

```
plotswithfilling = Table[
  Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[i, 1], x] Exp[-Sqrt[i]/4] /. 
      i -> Range[1, 3, 2] // Evaluate, {x, k, k + 1}, 
    PlotRange -> Full, Filling -> Axis, Axes -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> {ColorData[10][4 + k], 
      Darker[ColorData[10][4 + k], 0.3]}], {k, -3, 5}];

Options[#, AxesOrigin] & /@ plotswithfilling // Column
```

[image]

Two easy fixes: (1) Change `Filling -> Axis` to `Filling -> 0` or (2) add the option  `AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, 0}`

to get

[image]

Comment: When phrased like this is makes perfect sense :-) Sometimes mathematica is too smart!